# Ionic 3/Angular Transition on scope variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Imagine I have got something like this in my `.html` file

```
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>

<button clear block ion-button (click)="setText()">Set Text</button>
```

and the `setText()` function in my `.ts` file.

```
public text: string;

public setText () : void {
  this.text += 'a';
}
```

Is it possbile to give this function a simple transition, like a `fade` or something similar?

Comment: Read about animate.css

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: It can be useful [link](https://youtu.be/8pOsJDZbJk0?t=9m13s)